# Implement prevent other MacOS running app showing window why open my flutter app

Tags: flutter

Now I want to implement the flutter app which have function to prevent some selected MaOS running  apps showing there window (more detail, after user select some apps to prevent for showing so while my app is running, user clicks on other running app, my app will prevent it from showing so user only focus on my productivity app without distraction by other apps.

Is there anyway I can implement this function, please help me with this.